# HTTP Status 500 - java.lang.NullPointerException Servlet + jsp

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, servlets

So here is the thing. I try to display some list of messages on main page of the web-site by using jsp. But when the tomcat server starts, I'm watching only on this error "HTTP Status 500 - java.lang.NullPointerException" that points to the line "for (Message message : messageList)"

Here is the code of servlet:

```
public class MainPageServlet extends HttpServlet {

@Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    MessageManager manager = new MessageManager();
    List<Message> messageList = manager.getMessages();

    request.setAttribute("messages", messageList);

    request.getRequestDispatcher("/main-page.jsp").include(request, response); } }
```

And here is a part of jsp:

```
<%
List<Message> messageList = (List<Message>) request.getAttribute("messages");
for (Message message : messageList) {
%>
<div class="row" style="margin-top: 15px">
<div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
    <div class="panel panel-primary">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h3 class="panel-title">
                <%= message.getLogin()%>
            </h3>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
            <%= message.getMessage() %>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-footer">
            Posted at: <%= message.getDate() %>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
<%
}
%>
```

I've tested on result of getting messageList and it's 100% ok. So where is the bug?
Thnx in advance for helping!

Comment: Does `getMessages()` return `null`?

Comment: no, it's returning a list of messages. I've made a simple test by displaying resulted list in console - everything is ok.

Comment: Did you check whether `messageList` contains null items?

Answer (score 0):

In your scriptlet first check your messages is not null. Like,

```
if (request.getAttribute("messages") != null){
   List<Message> messageList = (List<Message>) request.getAttribute("messages");
   for (Message message : messageList) {
%>
<div class="row" style="margin-top: 15px">
<div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
<div class="panel panel-primary">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        <h3 class="panel-title">
            <%= message.getLogin()%>
        </h3>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
        <%= message.getMessage() %>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-footer">
        Posted at: <%= message.getDate() %>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<%
  }
}
 %>
```

So you may not come across null pointer exception. If you are not getting any data via request use session to send the values across the page. Try and let me know..

Comment: using "if-dummy" web-site works, but w/o messages. So maybe you can give advice how to display gathered info on the web-site after it's loaded?

Comment: It means you are not getting any data in your jsp page. Have you tried session instead of request as i mentioned above?

Answer (score 0):

```
List<Message> messageList = (List<Message>) request.getAttribute("messages");
```

here you didn't type cast..

```
<%MainPageServlet  messageList = (MainPageServlet) request.getAttribute("messages"); %>
```

try this,it may help you

**NOTE:  NOT TESTED**